# React Testing Library tests seem to be affecting each other

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

For some reason, when I run these tests, the last test (clicking clear button removes filters) fails when I have it at the end of the document. When I move the whole `clear button` describes block up to before the previous test (validates date ranges and displays correct messages), it passes.

When it fails, it says the reason for failure is from the assertion:

```
expect(
        screen.getByText(
          t('endDateLessThanStart'),
        ),
      ).toBeInTheDocument();
```

which is actually from the test above it. So somehow, that test is affecting the last test.

Also, it only fails when I include the line `await userEvent.type(dateInput, yesterday);`. When I take that line out, everything passes.

Here's the tests:

```
import React from 'react';

import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';

import { render, t } from '/utils';

import { Filters } from './Filters';

const updateFilters = jest.fn();

const defaultEndDate = Date.now();
const defaultEndDateDayJS = dayjs(defaultEndDate);
const yesterday = defaultEndDateDayJS.subtract(1, 'day').toISOString();
const tomorrow = defaultEndDateDayJS.add(1, 'day').toISOString();

describe('Filters', () => {
  it('validates date ranges and displays correct messages', async () => {
    render(<Filters updateFilters={updateFilters} />);

    const dateInputs = screen.getAllByPlaceholderText(
      t('chooseOption'),
    );

    const validateRange = async (
      startDate: HTMLElement,
      endDate: HTMLElement,
    ) => {
      await userEvent.clear(endDate);
      await userEvent.type(endDate, `${yesterday}`);

      expect(
        screen.getByText(
          t('endDateLessThanStart'),
        ),
      ).toBeInTheDocument();

      await userEvent.clear(endDate);
      await userEvent.type(endDate, `${tomorrow}`);

      expect(
        screen.getByText(
          t('endDateGreaterThanNow'),
        ),
      ).toBeInTheDocument();

      await userEvent.clear(endDate);
      await userEvent.type(endDate, 'abc');

      expect(
        screen.getByText(t('useISOFormat')),
      ).toBeInTheDocument();

      await userEvent.clear(startDate);
      await userEvent.clear(endDate);

      const date1 = defaultEndDateDayJS.subtract(4, 'day').toISOString();
      const date2 = defaultEndDateDayJS.subtract(2, 'day').toISOString();
      await userEvent.type(startDate, date1);
      await userEvent.type(endDate, date2);

      expect(
        screen.getAllByText(t('dateRangeHelpText')),
      ).toHaveLength(3);

      await userEvent.clear(startDate);
      await userEvent.clear(endDate);
      await userEvent.type(startDate, yesterday);
      await userEvent.type(endDate, defaultEndDateDayJS.toISOString());

      expect(
        screen.getAllByText(t('dateRangeHelpText')),
      ).toHaveLength(3);
    };

    await validateRange(dateInputs[0], dateInputs[1]);
    await validateRange(dateInputs[2], dateInputs[3]);
    await validateRange(dateInputs[4], dateInputs[5]);
  });

  describe('clear button', () => {
    test('clear button renders and is disabled by default', () => {
      render(<Filters updateFilters={updateFilters} />);
      const clearButton = screen.getByRole('button', {
        name: `${t('clear')} ${t('filters')}`,
      });
      expect(clearButton).toBeInTheDocument();
      expect(clearButton).toBeDisabled();
    });

    test('clicking clear button removes filters', async () => {
      render(<Filters updateFilters={updateFilters} />);
      const clearButton = screen.getByRole('button', {
        name: `${t('clear')} ${t(
          'filters',
        )}`,
      });
      const input = screen.getAllByPlaceholderText<HTMLInputElement>(
        t('displayAll'),
      )[2];

      const dateInput = screen.getAllByPlaceholderText<HTMLInputElement>(
        t('displayAll'),
      )[0];

      await userEvent.type(dateInput, yesterday);
      await userEvent.type(input, 'test');
      await userEvent.click(clearButton);

      setTimeout(() => expect(input).toHaveValue(''), 500);
      setTimeout(() => expect(clearButton).toBeDisabled(), 500);
    });
  });
});
```